# Azure SDK 2.5.1 for vs2013 update notification always exists

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I installed Azure SDK 2.5.1 from the pack downloaded from Microsoft's website, and the installation completed. However, in VS2013 in the "Extensions and Updates" dialog, it still shows the update notification for Azure 2.5.1.

Did I not install it correctly?

Comment: One of posible solution
[May be it is solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281710/azure-sdk-2-5-1-fails-to-publish-cloudservice

Comment: This isn't the same problem, although I tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not the only one having this problem (I am, too).  I found a thread on the MSDN forums (["Azure SDK 2.5.1 install issues"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4ac5c257-a451-4531-a5af-dffd8d51caf3/azure-sdk-251-install-issues?forum=windowsazuredevelopment)), but so far (as of ~ 1 PM on 4/4) I haven't found anyone with a posted solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that worked for me.

1. After the platform installer fails, click on the "Click here to see additional software to be installed and review the associated Microsoft license terms."
2. In the new window, click "Direct Download Link" for each component listed.  Each click will download an installer.  Run it, then click the next "Direct Download Link".  Install.  Repeat until all items are installed.
3. Start VS 2013 and everything will be there.  You will have Quick Starts and the "Azure API App (Preview)" that is referenced in this great little tutorial.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-dotnet-create-api-app/

Comment: The thing is the platform installer doesn't fail but install's the SDK all the way ... with "success" but then Visual Studio 2013 update 4 doesn't take that into account and continuously show's the update notification.

Comment: My situation was a little different then because I didn't have any of the tools, templates, or publish profiles for "Azure API App".  Once I did the manual direct link installs, all the tool support started showing in VS 2013 for me.  To confirm I still see the update available and pending under "Extensions and Updates" too so I guess in the end my steps don't resolve the original question/issue.  It does, however, allow me to work.