# Azure continuous deployment error Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Packaging

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Out of nowhere I started getting this error when I try to deploy my project to cloud service (using continuous deployment and hosted build controller.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.5\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets (2917): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Packaging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281710/azure-sdk-2-5-1-fails-to-publish-cloudservice), but it didn't help me.

Also I noticed I didn't even have  folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\
```

I only have v10.0, v11.0, v12.0, so I manually created v14.0 and copied folder Windows Azure Tools form v12.0 but it didn't help.

**EDIT**

I've updated Azure tools to 2.6 but the problem and error message remains the same.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Tell me if you solved your prolbem, I have the same problem(I created another build controller, and it doesn't have this problem). It looks like it's specific to the Hosted Build Controller.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem now.  Never had this before.

Comment: Not only do you have to install the 2.6 SDK, but you also have to tell the Azure Deployment project to use the 2.6 SDK. this is most easily accomplished by going to the properties page of the project and there's a nifty button that appears that will "upgrade" it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error occurring today on Visual Studio Online's Host Build Controller. I assume you are using the same thing by your talk of Azure & Continuous Integration.

I noticed that they just released Azure SDK 2.6 support on the build controller in the last day or so. I feel that this may have somehow caused the problem.

I updated my cloud project to use 2.6, checked in, and everything was fine again.  Some ccproj details:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' ">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Windows Azure Tools\2.6\</CloudExtensionsDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This helped :D After first check-in my build was queued for too long, so I went to sleep and left it over night, but nothing, it was still in the queue. So I cancelled that build, made another check-in and now it is fine. Thank you very much (I even contacted Azure Dev support, and I was on Skyepe with them for an about hour, but they couldn't find solution either)

Answer (score 0):

do you updated your Azure SDK for .NET to 2.5.1?
I have experienced this issue before when I updated the Azure SDK for .NET to 2.5.1

Microsoft has just recently release Azure SDK for .NET version 2.6 and I suggest you should try this. I believe this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update Azure SDK to version 2.6 and after, update your Azure project's Application.

You can do this within the project's properties, by clicking the button to update Microsoft Azure Tools version from 2.5.1 to 2.6.

Comment: Hey that  didn't help me :(

Comment: The VSO Host Build Controller has only been had support for Azure SDK 2.6 for about a day.  I checked [this page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/build/hosted-build-controller-vs) a couple of days ago and there was no SDK 2.6 support, but now I see there is (I wish they had a changelog for these things). I wonder if this is the reason for the sudden error...

Answer (score 0):

"try adding /p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false to your msbuild arguments in addition to /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0, that has helped others workaround that same issue."

from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc434580-cf81-44eb-9382-cd1b9fc9583a/microsoft-azure-sdk-v26-issue-with-cloud-builds?forum=TFService